# New to GCP and Cloud Run and pretty new to .Net. Can't find any code samples of logging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, google-cloud-run

I am doing some proof-of-concept work with Cloud Run and .NET 7. Am using the Miminal APIs patterns. I want to get logging right before proceeding. I saw mention of Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore - which I assume is the correct framework for logging of .NET in Cloud Run (but not even sure about that). My Googling skills are failing me. I can't find a complete code sample.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore/latest

Comment: In many cases, you do not need to do anything special. Cloud Run captures messages written to `stdout` and `stderr`. Link to the .NET logging framework: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/integrate/dotnet

Comment: That link was helpful - I hadn't see it before. There is a fourth option that should be in that list, which is to use Google.Cloud.Logging.Console, which modifies the native logging to format to the JSON that the GCP logger likes. 

I made a minimal sample using with both Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3 and Google.Cloud.Logging.Console and they both work. Now hoping someone can chime in about the pros and cons of there four logging options.

Comment: Opinions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. As a suggestion, modify your post and show examples of the four methods. That might generate answers with code-based comments that would be on-topic.

Comment: I've decided to use Google.Cloud.Logging.Console and it seems to get the job done. The docs show the couple of lines that you have to add.

Answer (score -1):

I've decided to use Google.Cloud.Logging.Console and it seems to get the job done. The docs show the couple of lines that you have to add.